# What is wrong with this simple CSS and html chess layout? (Short code)

Tags: html, css, chess

I am making a chessboard and my main problem is that after I set up the first two rows of the board, the pawn insertion alters the color of the dark squares.

So the board has the class "main" and is colored white, the squares(class="box) are either the same color as the board (white) or brown. The component (pawn) is an SVG. Upon adding the pawn ID to a square, it nullifies the squares color. This is fine for the white squares, but a problem with the brown squares.

here is the code

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.main {
  height: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 10% 15%;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background: burlywood;
}

#pawn {
  background: url(https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg) center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `#id`s must be unique. So redo `#id` for each pawn. (ex. `pawn1`, `pawn2`, etc.). Also, `background-size: cover` will make the image stretch to all sides of it's container thereby covering it.

Comment: BTW, have you actually seen the results of your example? It resembles nothing like what was described.

Comment: Try it on visual code or jsfiddle. it does not work on snippet.

Comment: Post the link to the fiddle.

Comment: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` will make 9 columns -- chessboards have 8 columns.

Comment: @Deerman1989 check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the height and width % to work, you should give a height and width to its parent, because thats what they will take as 100%. In this case you had % in main but not stated a width nor height in the body tag.

In this case you can't use those % so I used static px in order to do it faster and to not re-structure the html.

The problem you had with the backgrounds is that when you add an image as a background it overwrites the previous background, so in order to have a transparent image with a styled background you have to add it as content (img) of the container with that background.

I also changed the main class for the main tag and replaced id pawn as you should not have more that one tag with the same id, in other words, it should be unique, if you want to use more, use a class.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 10% 15%;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background: burlywood;
}

img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the same id for more than one tag, and istead of using a class named "main" you can use the tag <main>

Comment: This still nullifies the background color of a square so the pawns all seem to be on white squares.

Comment: Thanks. You could of course have multiple background images so you don't need to add img elements to the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I am trying to make a chess game and the css board setup seems to be a nightmare. I already have the chess game algorithm ready but the css seems to be a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you imported svg as a background picture. so it is not a real svg anymore. This svg picture overrides the box property.
You can achieve what you want by placing the svg one by one in the div. Good Luck!

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        body {
      background-color: grey;
    }
    
    .main {
      height: 50%;
      width: 70%;
      margin: 10% 15%;
      background-color: white;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .box {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .box:nth-child(even) {
      background: burlywood;
    }
    /*
    #pawn {
      background: url(https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg) center;
      background-size: cover;
    }*/
    </style>
    <body>
    
      <div class="main">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
        <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0"width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
        <div class="box" id="pawn"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%"  viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M6240 9660 c-210 -37 -369 -113 -507 -244 -142 -134 -246 -294 -278 -427 -19 -83 -19 -215 1 -319 42 -221 151 -394 326 -517 84 -59 128 -104 128 -132 0 -27 -37 -69 -78 -90 -21 -10 -93 -37 -162 -61 -141 -48 -277 -111 -315 -146 -19 -17 -25 -33 -25 -63 0 -66 17 -88 124 -159 273 -179 387 -297 461 -481 60 -148 91 -444 75 -725 -15 -251 -48 -401 -126 -561 -76 -159 -177 -271 -394 -438 -98 -75 -103 -83 -125 -182 -10 -47 -72 -98 -146 -120 -199 -58 -350 -173 -472 -358 -65 -97 -100 -178 -127 -290 -37 -154 -25 -237 46 -316 26 -29 44 -58 42 -68 -2 -10 -37 -36 -78 -58 -95 -53 -129 -95 -136 -166 -14 -146 92 -208 445 -259 805 -116 2540 -100 3129 29 214 47 282 98 282 211 0 83 -41 135 -150 190 -49 25 -70 45 -70 66 0 2 18 24 40 48 53 58 70 102 70 183 0 321 -278 690 -586 778 -128 37 -166 72 -185 167 -13 66 -7 59 -208 219 -181 144 -292 299 -360 504 -47 144 -62 256 -68 503 -10 422 37 637 182 830 63 84 138 148 313 267 131 89 148 104 161 141 13 37 12 44 -5 80 -16 33 -32 46 -113 85 -51 26 -150 66 -220 89 -194 66 -234 92 -234 150 0 38 26 66 124 135 218 153 340 398 340 680 0 161 -45 287 -152 428 -181 239 -398 365 -702 406 -103 14 -142 13 -267 -9z"/>
    </g>
    </svg></div>
    
    
      </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, AFAIK it's fine normally to use an svg as a background - could you explain why it's not an svg anymore?

Answer (score 0):

In setting the pawn SVG as a background you are getting rid of other background settings - in this case the background of the alternate squares.

A more explicit setting of background-color and background-image will make sure that the color is not overwritten. The SVG has transparent background itself so the background color of the square will show through.

To ensure that, whatever the aspect ratio of a piece's SVG, it's in the square use contain rather than cover and set the background image to not repeat and to be centered.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.main {
  height: 50vmin;
  width: 50vmin;
  margin: 10% 15%;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

#pawn {
  background-image: url(https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box" id="pawn"></div>
  </div>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  margin: 10% 15%;
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background: burlywood;
}

img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>

    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
    <div class="box"><img class="pawn" src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/3413417.svg" alt="pawn"></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

There are other problems in the given code. You may like to investigate the use of vmin as a unit to define a square (as that will ensure responsiveness whatever the aspect ratio of the viewport) and also the use of grid is a little odd (needing 9 files). It may be more easy to relate the layout to a chess board by dropping grid and having 8 squares contained in a div with class rank. This will make the coloring simpler and ensure the layout is square and should help in future when more ranks are added. However, all that are subects for a different question.